# Firestore data structure for medium post

Tags: data-structures, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to model a post structure like those in medium, with alternating paragraphs and photos.

[title]

[subTitle]

[main photo]

[paragraph 1]

[paragraph 2]

[photo 1]

[paragraph 3]

[photo 2]

[photo 3]

...

In order to maintain the order of paragraphs and photos, I am thinking of using array of object to model the post as below:

Posts (collection)

- postId (document)

  - content: (Array)

    - title: string (Object)
    - subTitle: string (Object)
    - mainPhotoURL: string (Object)
    - paragraph: string (Object)
    - paragraph: string (Object)
    - photoURL: string (Object)
    - paragraph: string (Object)
    - ...

Any comment on this thought? Any other data structure suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore document has a limit of 1MB. Arrays aren't scalable and addition/deletion is quite expensive and not yet available in all of admin SDKs. Every content should have it's own document.
Just like.

postId (document)

title: string (Object)

subTitle: string (Object)

mainPhotoURL: string (Object)

paragraph: string (Object)

paragraph: string (Object)

photoURL: string (Object)

paragraph: string (Object)

...

Comment: how to keep track of the order of paragraph and photoURL?

Comment: I now have a sub-collection called 'content' as a field of post document, in the 'content' sub-collection, I store content elements such as paragraph(string) or photoURL(string) in separate document, but in order to maintain the order, I have to add 'order' field to each document, so I can later on query with orderBy('order') to get the correct order of these content elements. Is this an appropriate way to do?

Comment: Just reference the collection and add a query 'orderBy' on any field.